# SharedPreferences Problem

Tags: android

i am using SharedPreferences in my code that will store last state of my check box. when i focefuly stop my application through setting>> application it dosn't save it's previous state. what is the problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling Editor.commit() when you make a change?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you implement the OnSavedInstanceState function and save all you want to be saved in there.